# How to get all checked checkboxes in *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have some checkboxes generated from an array of objects get from an API, each checkbox is a plate ingredient which can be toggled, and when the user finished to customize the plate he should be able to submit the plate with it's ingredients.

So i have an *ngFor like this where i render the ingredients of the plate:

```
          <div
            class="col-sm-6 affiancato"
            *ngFor="let ingrediente of ingredientiPlu"
          >
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="custom-constrol">
                <input
                  class="form-check-input"
                  checked="true"
                  type="checkbox"
                  [value]="ingrediente"
                  (change)="checkVariante(ingrediente, $event)"
                />
                {{ ingrediente.desc }}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

While ingrediente is the following class:

```
export class Varianti {
    constructor(
        public id?: string,
        public desc?: string,
        public prezzo?: number,
        public prezzo_meno?: number,
        public menu?: number[],
        public stato?: string,
        public ingrediente?: boolean
    ){}
}
```

`variante.ingrediente` is a property of the object by which i filter the object in two sub arrays:

```
   varianti.filter((variante: Varianti) => {
      variante.ingrediente
        ? this.ingredientiPlu.push(variante)
        : this.variantiPlu.push(variante);
    });
```

How can i get all checked checkboxes Varianti object on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

In your change funtion, you could do something like this:

```
checkVariante(): void {
   /** other code */

   /** on change filter all true ingrediente to a component variable allChecked */
   this.allChecked = this.ingredientiPlu.filter(i => i.ingrediente);
}
```

Comment: Actually `ingrediente: boolean` is not the field which says if the object is checked or not but it's a property of the object.

Comment: What does control it then? I am confused because at the end of your question you state you want to get all Checked boxes, which correspond to the associated Varianti object. If that's the case you should be using [ngModel] to bind the value of ingrediente  to the checkbox

Comment: actually i can't add another parameter to Varianti which will manage if the object is checked or not as i have to resend the object to the server as it is. so i was looking something like a loop or idk what that will loop through the checkboxes and get the object value from those checked

Comment: Which value sets the initial state of the checkbox?

Comment: by default checked is not set so the checkboxes are not checked while another category of checkboxes has checked set to true in html by default

Answer (score -1):

Solved by creating an array of `Varianti` to which i push or remove the object on `(change)` like the following:

```
      <div
        class="col-sm-6 affiancato"
        *ngFor="let variante of variantiPlu"
      >
            <input
              class="form-check-input"
              type="checkbox"
              (change)="checkVariante(variante, $event)"
            />
            {{
              variante.desc 
            }}
      </div>

  checkVariante(oVariante: Varianti, event: any): void {
    const variante = Object.assign({}, oVariante); // cloning Varianti object to don't affect the original one.
    if (event.target.checked) { // checking if the checkbox has been checked
        variante.prezzo = variante.ingrediente ? 0 : variante.prezzo; // changing object properties
        variante.stato = variante.ingrediente ? 'SENZA' : 'PIU';
        this.checkedVariants.push(variante); // pushing object to Varianti[]
    }else {
      this.checkedVariants = this.checkedVariants.filter(v => v.id !== variante.id); // if the checkbox has been unchecked removing the object from the array
    }
    console.log(this.checkedVariants);
  }
```